# Как используя чистый ActiveForm, запихнуть 2 поля input в одно поле модели? yii2

Tags: php, yii2, activeform

В таблице `users` есть поле `username`, при этом при регистрации будет вместо `username` 2 инпута `name` и `surname`. Каким образом можно занести в поле `username` суммарное значение 2х инпутов `name + surname`, не меняя принцип валидации ActiveForm и не добавляя лишний JS код?

P.S. вопрос не сильно принципиальный, в принципе ничего страшного не произойдет, если в таблице вместо username будут 2 поля name и surname, однако все равно любопытно узнать ответ на вышепоставленный вопрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если без js, только так:

```
public $name = null;
public $surname = null;

public function beforeValidate() 
{
    if ($this->$name !== null)
        $this->username = $this->name . ' ' . $this->surname;

    return parent::beforeValidate();
}
```

Или, как вариант, использовать сценарии

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но я уже сам додумался, как это реализовать иначе.

Answer (score 0):

Придумал все-таки способ, как это реализовать, пусть и не так лаконично, как предложили выше, но тоже имеет право на существование.

В контроллер в методе регистрации меняем код на

```
public function actionSignup()
    {
        $model = new SignupForm();
        // объявляем объект из анонимного класса
        $obj = new class extends SignupForm{
            public $name;
            public $surname;
            };
        if (Yii::$app->request->isPost) {
            // так как класс анонимный, его включ в массиве $_POST выглядит мягко скажем не очень, поэтому значения name и surname можно найти либо рекурсией, либо регуляркой, я выбрал регулярку.
            preg_match('/s\:[\d]+\:\"'.preg_quote("surname").'\";s\:[\d]+\:\"(.*?)\"/', serialize(Yii::$app->request->post()), $rgMatches);
            preg_match('/s\:[\d]+\:\"'.preg_quote("name").'\";s\:[\d]+\:\"(.*?)\"/', serialize(Yii::$app->request->post()), $rgMatches2);
            // так как нельзя изменить данные $app->request->post() создаем новую переменную для ввода данных в модель $load
            $load = Yii::$app->request->post();
            $load['SignupForm']['username'] = $rgMatches2[1]." ".$rgMatches[1];
            if ($model->load($load)) {
                if ($user = $model->signup()) {
                    if (Yii::$app->getUser()->login($user)) {
                        return $this->goHome();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return $this->render('signup', [
            'model' => $model,
            'obj' => $obj
        ]);
    }
```

В представлении просто добавляем 2 инпута привязанных к объекту $obj

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'form-signup']); ?>

                <?= $form->field($model, 'username')->textInput(['autofocus' => true]) ?>
                <?= $form->field($obj, 'name')->textInput() ?>
                <?= $form->field($obj, 'surname')->textInput() ?>
                <?= $form->field($model, 'email') ?>

                <?= $form->field($model, 'password')->passwordInput() ?>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <?= Html::submitButton('Signup', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'name' => 'signup-button']) ?>
                </div>

            <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Comment: А чем не угодил ответ который выше? Для чего городить весь этот лишний код????????

Comment: Я поставил ответу выше балл и отметил галочкой + в своем ответе написал, что этот вариант не такой лаконичный, как выше, но тоже имеет право на существование. Мне чем-то не угодил ответ выше? В чем проблема?